# How do you modify the apache 403 error displayed when a directory is forbidden

Tags: php, .htaccess

Say you deny access to certain folders or files and you want to serve your custom error messages instead of something like this

You don't have permission to access /classes/classname.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at webdev Port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Apache configuration - specifically, [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html).

You'll add a line to your `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbidden.html
```